# Moq Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, testing, moq

I am using entity framework db first approach and generated `edmx` file.

I am trying to implement `enter code here` Unit testing with `MOQ` framework.

Here is my code

```
[TestMethod]
    public void DeleteApplication()
    {
        var mockContext = new Mock<ARMSContext>();
        var data = GetMemoryApplications();
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Application>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Application>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Application>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Application>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Application>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        var test=appcontroller.Delete(1, 1);

    }
```

I am getting the `Parent does not have..` exception while calling `mockSet.Object`.

could you pls to resolve this exception?

Comment: Also post stack trace of error. But looking error it seems you are trying to create instance of some object which do not have public constructor.

Comment: Where is `mockSet.Object` ?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have given, I can't see how you are using `Mock<DbSet<Application>>`, nor `Mock<ARMSContext>`.

Here is the sample given from MSDNs "[Testing with a mocking framework (EF6 onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx#queryTest)", which hooks the `DbSet` up to the `Context`:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllBlogs_orders_by_name()
    {
        var data = new List<Blog>
        {
            new Blog { Name = "BBB" },
            new Blog { Name = "ZZZ" },
            new Blog { Name = "AAA" },
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        var mockContext = new Mock<BloggingContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Blogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var service = new BlogService(mockContext.Object);
        var blogs = service.GetAllBlogs();

        Assert.AreEqual(3, blogs.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("AAA", blogs[0].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("BBB", blogs[1].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("ZZZ", blogs[2].Name);
    }
}
```